# How do I get rid of this error showing up in my Sanity desk tool?

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I am new to Sanity. Can someone please help me? I'm getting this error in my Sanity Desk tool whenever I go to my /pins document.

I have an idea on what it could be, since it shows that there's a data within the pins document that doesn't contain an image, yet I'm having troubles on how to delete a data from a document in Sanity. I would really appreciate any help.

Stack Trace

```
Error: Malformed asset _ref ''. Expected an id like "image-Tb9Ew8CXIwaY6R1kjMvI0uRR-2000x3000-jpg".
    at parseAssetId (/static/js/app.bundle.js:48583:13)
    at urlForImage (/static/js/app.bundle.js:48735:17)
    at ImageUrlBuilder.url (/static/js/app.bundle.js:49183:12)
    at http://localhost:3333/static/js/app.bundle.js:79917:149
    at renderMedia (/static/js/app.bundle.js:45642:12)
    at Media (/static/js/app.bundle.js:45628:6)
    at renderWithHooks (/static/js/vendor.bundle.js:17945:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (/static/js/vendor.bundle.js:20624:13)
    at beginWork (/static/js/vendor.bundle.js:21738:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/static/js/vendor.bundle.js:3330:14)

Component Stack
<br>
    in StructureError (created by DeskToolRoot)
    in DeskToolRoot (created by RenderTool)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by RenderTool)
    in RenderTool (created by SchemaErrorReporter)
    in RouteScope (created by SchemaErrorReporter)
    in div (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (created by ForwardRef(Box))
    in ForwardRef(Box) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef(Flex))
    in ForwardRef(Flex) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by SchemaErrorReporter)
    in div (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (created by ForwardRef(Box))
    in ForwardRef(Box) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef(Flex))
    in ForwardRef(Flex) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by SchemaErrorReporter)
    in div (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (created by ForwardRef(Box))
    in ForwardRef(Box) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef(Flex))
    in ForwardRef(Flex) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by SchemaErrorReporter)
    in SchemaErrorReporter (created by DefaultLayout)
    in DefaultLayout (created by DefaultLayoutRoot)
    in RouterProvider (created by DefaultLayoutRoot)
    in LoginWrapper (created by NormalizedLoginWrapper)
    in NormalizedLoginWrapper (created by DefaultLayoutRoot)
    in DefaultLayoutRoot (created by AppProvider)
    in div (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (created by ForwardRef(Box))
    in ForwardRef(Box) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by ForwardRef(Card))
    in Fe (created by ThemeProvider)
    in ThemeProvider (created by ThemeColorProvider)
    in ThemeColorProvider (created by ForwardRef(Card))
    in ForwardRef(Card) (created by Styled(Component))
    in Styled(Component) (created by AppProvider)
    in SnackbarProvider (created by AppProvider)
    in ToastProvider (created by AppProvider)
    in LayerProvider (created by AppProvider)
    in PortalProvider (created by AppProvider)
    in UserColorManagerProvider (created by AppProvider)
    in AppProvider (created by SanityRoot)
    in Fe (created by ThemeProvider)
    in ThemeProvider (created by SanityRoot)
    in ZIndexProvider (created by SanityRoot)
    in SanityRoot
    in AppContainer
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have references in Sanity, you should expand them to access its image data. Maybe you forgot incluid it in your query.

Example:

```
const query = groq`
    *[_type == "project"] {
    ...,
    sectionNameToExpand[]->
    }
`
```

Note: groq is from next-sanity library